# Where to execute Flyway.migrate()?

Tags: hibernate, jax-rs, flyway

I am developing my JAX-RS application using Hibernate JPA, with settings like `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto='create-drop'` to create the table in my postgresql db.

Obviously, this is catastrophic in production.

Recently, I discovered Flyway, and would like to give it a try. It has a few approach to migrate the changes, like command-line or API.

If I am not mistaken, command-line approach requires me to execute the changes separately, while the API approach will execute the migration automatically. However, where is the `main` function in JAXRS application?

Hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

As said in [Flyway Docs](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/), you can use API approach in order to start migration like:

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(...);
flyway.migrate();
```

The only necessary thing is to run this code snippet during the web application initialization process. Use standard Servlet approach for this, something like:

```
@WebListener
public class AppStartupListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        // configure datasource
        flyway.setDataSource(...);
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {}

}
```

Hope this will help.